# Making Oracle JDK automatically updateable in Ubuntu or GNU/Linux OS

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I'm facing a problem about Oracle JDK in my Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS OS.

I downloaded Oracle JDK ***Linux_x64 -version 8u131*** tar.gz file from [official website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). I extracted the file in ***/home/ashik/Applications/*** directory and I exported path in ***.bashrc*** file like,

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/ashik/Applications/jdk-8u131-linux-x64/
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

It's working fine but I want to make this jdk version auto upgradeable. If I use openjdk from official repository it provides update packages time to time. I want to do something like that for Oracle JDK. If Oracle release any updated version then it should be upgraded in my system automatically. In Microsoft Windows system this JDK informs when any update appear. Developers can upgrade the JDK if they want then. I want to do something like that.

I know there have some suggestions to use openjdk or using PPA but I don't want to do so. I want to get update file from Oracle directly. I know there has a way to download upgraded version from Oracle's website and replace it in that path but i don't want to follow any of these ways. I want to do something which will take care the whole updating system by itself automatically.

If there is any way to do so?

My System Information:

> OS: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS , DE: Gnome 3

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do this because you need to accept Oracle License agreement each time you download the software. OpenJDK is open source, Oracles JDK is not.

Comment: I know the difference between OpenJDK and Oracle JDK but in Windows system Oracle JDK notify that a new update is available though user's have to agree the license terms. Isn't there any way like this in GNU/Linux ?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a shell scrip to do this for you. If you want to automate accepting oracle license, you can do something like here:

https://github.com/appscode/Dockerfiles/blob/master/oracle-jdk/Dockerfile#L5

This is a common pattern used to build JDK docker images.

To download JDK archive from Oracle's website, you can use something like below:

`curl -b oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie -L 'http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u112-b15/server-jre-8u112-linux-x64.tar.gz'`

Comment: Thanks but as I mentioned, I don't want to use any PPA. That shell script is working with a PPA ( http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/ ) , but I want to make it from Oracle directly.